# wordpress redirecting all pages to homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a wordpress website www.spiderhost.asia, when i click on any link on the website it's redirecting to the homepage which I don't want, it was working perfectly few days back and I didn't change any config and anything in website , still it's not working properly.

I contacted server admin, wordpress admin regarding same but didn't find any solution for that.

Even I didn't make anychanges to htaccess

```
  # BEGIN WordPress
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
  </IfModule>

  # END WordPress
```

I need help resolving this

Comment: i think that issue is arise because of login funtionality or plugin.

Answer (score 0):

That htaccess file is saying that if the file or directory being queried does not exist and it is not `index.php`, then reroute to `index.php`. Make sure that the file you're trying to query exists (and that it's in the correct directory).

Comment: Yes all file are in same directory and they do exists

Comment: @dollar links seems '#' in url like '<a href="#">Hosting</a>'.

Comment: Woops, posted too soon.. Those are the headers I'm getting when trying to view some of the pages on your site. The reason why I can't determine with the information I have.

Comment: yes even i can see 301 in headers but i am unable to figure out why?

Comment: Whatever the reason is is something on your server. I cannot tell you why with the information I have, as there's tons of reasons this could be happening. Make sure the pages don't have code that send those headers. I have never used WordPress, but if you can, look at your admin panel or some equivalent where you would be able to change what pages redirect where. You could also look to see if there's any other htaccess files on your site. Other than that, I can't help a whole lot and recommend contacting their support or getting someone who can look at your code to try to figure it out.